# Why does Carol Marcus not recognize Khan in The Wrath of Khan?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-into-darkness, the-wrath-of-khan, star-trek-movies

I saw the new movie and went back and watched the wrath of khan on Netflix. I was a bit confused since I am not a real trekkie.

In *Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan*, Dr. Carol Marcus asks who Khan is. When I saw *Star Trek Into Darkness* this weekend, the young Carol Marcus was involved in the battle against the younger Khan. Why does she not know who he is several years later?

Answer (score 64):

*Star Trek Into Darkness* (the new movie) and *Star Trek The Wrath of Khan* (the old one) occur in two separate time lines. Essentially they are two different Carol Marcuses fighting two different Khans.

To see how the time lines split, watch *Star Trek* (2009).

Comment: thanx! saw the new movie and went back and watched the wrath of khan on netflix. was a bit confused since iam not a real treky

Comment: @joshuahood Welcome to the club. May your trek through Star Trek be long and prosperous.

Comment: @joshuahood If this does answer your question please remember to Accept it.

Comment: I'm all for calling it "Abrams Star Trek" from now on to eliminate such confusion.

Answer (score 6):

The events in Wrath of Khan still happened, but in the future when Nero travels back in time to the day of Kirk's birth, his presence creates an alternate time line

Spock explains it best...